# Algorithm for tiling video views

Tags: algorithm

Im making an app with video chat, and need to layout the participants in a zoom/teams like screen, filling a rectangle completely. Im locking the rotation to landscape, so I expect most video will be around 16/9 aspect ration, but this CAN be cropped, so its just something to aim for.

So given n tiles and an x times y rectangle, return a list of n rectangles with position and size which will together fill completely the outer rectangle.

Hoping someone knows about an algorithm which can do this while preserving aspect ratio as good as possible!

(I tried making a simple algorithm just progressively adding a column or a row, depending on which will make tiles aspect ratio match 16/9 closest, until there is enough sub-tiles, and then "joining" unused tiles afterwards, but it came out more complex and not as good as I hoped for...)

```cs
        public static List<Tile> GetTilePartitionResult(
            double width, double height, 
            int partitions, double preferredAspectRatio = 16d/9d)
        {
            var columns = 1;
            var rows = 1;
            var lastAddedRow = false;

            while (columns * rows < partitions)
            {
                // Find out if we should add a row or a column
                var rowAddedAspect = GetAspectRatio(width, height, rows + 1, columns);
                var columnAddedAspect = GetAspectRatio(width, height, rows, columns + 1);

                var rowAddedDiffFromIdeal = Math.Abs(preferredAspectRatio - rowAddedAspect);
                var columnAddedDiffFromIdeal = Math.Abs(preferredAspectRatio - columnAddedAspect);

                if (rowAddedDiffFromIdeal < columnAddedDiffFromIdeal)
                {
                    rows++;
                    lastAddedRow = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    columns++;
                    lastAddedRow = false;
                }
            }
            
            // Since after adding the "last" divider we might have an excess number of cells
            // So trim the "other" dimension until there is just enough tiles
            if (lastAddedRow)
            {
                while (((columns - 1) * rows) >= partitions) columns--;
            }
            else
            {
                while (((rows - 1) * columns) >= partitions) rows--;
            }

            // Assume we have the optimal grid/column setup, now distribute 
            // the tiles over this grid
            var tileHeight = height / rows;
            var tileWidth = width / columns;
            var tiles = new List<Tile>();
            for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                for (var column = 0; column < columns; column++)
                {
                    var newTile = new Tile
                    {
                        Height = tileHeight,
                        Width = tileWidth,
                        XOffSet = column * tileWidth,
                        YOffSet = row * tileHeight,
                        GridX = column,
                        GridY = row
                    };
                    tiles.Add(newTile);
                    
                    // Was this the last tile:
                    if (tiles.Count == partitions)
                    {
                        // Yes -> check if there is free space on this column
                        var extraColumns = columns - 1 - column;
                        if (extraColumns > 0)
                        {
                            // this extra space can be used in 2 ways,
                            // either expand current tile with, or expand
                            // height of previous row columns(the cells that are "above" the empty space)
                            // We decide which is best by choosing the resulting aspect ratio which
                            // most closely matches desired aspect ratio
                            var newWidthIfExpandingHorizontally = newTile.Width + (extraColumns * tileWidth);
                            var newHeightIfExpandingVertically = height * 2;
                            var aspectRatioIfExpandingHorizontally =
                                GetAspectRatio(newWidthIfExpandingHorizontally, height, 1, 1);
                            var aspectRationIfExpandingVertically =
                                GetAspectRatio(width, newHeightIfExpandingVertically, 1, 1);
                            if (Math.Abs(aspectRatioIfExpandingHorizontally - preferredAspectRatio) <
                                Math.Abs(aspectRationIfExpandingVertically - preferredAspectRatio))
                            {
                                // TODO: Should consider widening multiple "right" places tiles
                                // and move some down if extra cells > 1 .... Next time...
                                newTile.Width = newWidthIfExpandingHorizontally;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Find all tiles in previous row above empty space and change height:
                                var tilesToExpand = tiles.Where(t => t.GridY == row - 1 && t.GridX > column);
                                foreach (var tile in tilesToExpand)
                                {
                                    tile.Height = newHeightIfExpandingVertically;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // Nothing else to do on this column(we filled it...)
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return tiles;
        }
```

P.S. My code is in C#, but this is really a generic algorithm-question...

Comment: Can you please clarify which variables you are making available to change and how you will measure success?

Comment: My code is just to show more clearly what Im doing. Im not looking for code changes, but rather a better algorithm, I dont have any problems implementing it myself

Comment: My question relates only to the algorithm. It's unclear to me which exact variables are available to change and how much; as well as how do we exactly measure if the algorithm is successful.

Comment: You are right, I should provide success criteria. I will try to create some drawings of optimal partitioning